# Why autorest is replacing my custom struct by an object in Swagger?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, swashbuckle, autorest

I have created a custom `readonly` `struct` to define an immutable value type that I called `TenantId`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("ID={m_internalId.ToString()}")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(TenantIdJsonConverter))]
public readonly struct TenantId : IEquatable<TenantId>
{
    private readonly Guid m_internalId;

    public static TenantId New => new(Guid.NewGuid());

    private TenantId(Guid id)
    {
        m_internalId = id;
    }

    public TenantId(TenantId otherTenantId)
    {
       m_internalId = otherTenantId.m_internalId;
    }

    ...
}
```

I have also defined a contract called `PurchaseContract` that is part of an HTTP response:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public sealed class PurchaseContract
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tenantId")]
    public TenantId TenantId { get; }
        
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "total")]
    public double Total { get; }
}
```

Finally, I have set up an HTTP triggered function that will return an instance of `PurchaseContract`. For now, it has been described in the `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute`:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Purchases")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PurchaseContract), (int) HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[FunctionName("v1-get-purchase")]
public Task<IActionResult> RunAsync
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "v1/purchases")]
    HttpRequest httpRequest,
    [SwaggerIgnore] 
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal
)
{
    //  Stuff to do.
    return Task.FromResult((IActionResult)new OkResult());
}
```

In my `Startup` class, I am setting up swagger like this:

```
private static void ConfigureSwashBuckle(IFunctionsHostBuilder functionsHostBuilder)
{
    functionsHostBuilder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), options =>
            {
                options.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
                options.AddCodeParameter = true;
                options.PrependOperationWithRoutePrefix = true;
                options.XmlPath = "FunctionApp.xml";
                options.Documents = new []
                {
                    new SwaggerDocument
                    {
                        Title = "My API,
                        Version = "v1",
                        Name = "v1",
                        Description = "Description of my API",
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```

In the swagger UI page, I can see that it looks good:

[image: Swagger page]

**Question**

There is an unexpected outcome when creating a C# client using Autorest. Somehow, the `TenantId` struct is dropped and replaced by an `object` instead:

[image: TenantId is dropped and replaced by an Object]

Why is that and what should I do to have an autogenerated `TenantId`, like the `PurchaseContract` in the client as well?

**Details**

Here is the version information.

- Function App V3 running on netcore3.1;
- OpenApi 3.0;
- Autorest Core 3.0.6274, autorest.csharp' (~2.3.79->2.3.91) and autorest.modeler' (2.3.55->2.3.55);
- NuGet package [AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle](https://github.com/vitalybibikov/AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started investigating the source code of [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) to find out how my `readonly` `struct` was interpreted. It all happens in the class [JsonSerializerDataContractResolver](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/SchemaGenerator/JsonSerializerDataContractResolver.cs), in the method `GetDataContractForType` which determines the `DataContract` for the provided type:

```
public DataContract GetDataContractForType(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsOneOf(typeof(object), typeof(JsonDocument), typeof(JsonElement)))
    {
        ...
    }

    if (PrimitiveTypesAndFormats.ContainsKey(type))
    {
        ...
    }

    if (type.IsEnum)
    {
        ...
    }

    if (IsSupportedDictionary(type, out Type keyType, out Type valueType))
    {
        ...
    }

    if (IsSupportedCollection(type, out Type itemType))
    {
        ...
    }

    return DataContract.ForObject(
        underlyingType: type,
        properties: GetDataPropertiesFor(type, out Type extensionDataType),
        extensionDataType: extensionDataType,
        jsonConverter: JsonConverterFunc);
}
```

My custom `struct` `TenantId` does not match any of these conditions and, consequently, it falls back to being considered an `object` (last statement).

I then moved on to look at the existing [tests](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/SchemaGenerator/JsonSerializerSchemaGeneratorTests.cs) to see how the class was used and see if I could change anything. Surprisingly, I found a test called `GenerateSchema_SupportsOption_CustomTypeMappings` (line 356) which shows a way to provide a custom mapping (see the first statement of the method):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(typeof(ComplexType), typeof(ComplexType), "string")]
[InlineData(typeof(GenericType<int, string>), typeof(GenericType<int, string>), "string")]
[InlineData(typeof(GenericType<,>), typeof(GenericType<int, int>), "string")]
public void GenerateSchema_SupportsOption_CustomTypeMappings(
            Type mappingType,
            Type type,
            string expectedSchemaType)
{
    var subject = Subject(configureGenerator: c => c.CustomTypeMappings.Add(mappingType, () => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" }));

    var schema = subject.GenerateSchema(type, new SchemaRepository());

    Assert.Equal(expectedSchemaType, schema.Type);
    Assert.Empty(schema.Properties);
}
```

In my case, I would like to have my `TenantId` to be mapped to a `string`. To do so, I edited the configuration of SwashBuckle when my Function App starts:

```
private static void ConfigureSwashBuckle(IFunctionsHostBuilder functionsHostBuilder)
{
    functionsHostBuilder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), options =>
    {
        ...
        options.ConfigureSwaggerGen = (swaggerGenOptions) => swaggerGenOptions.MapType<TenantId>(() => new OpenApiSchema {Type = "string"});
    });
}
```

And here it is, the `TenantId` is now considered a `string` in Swagger.

[image: TenantId as a string]